# Как в функции разобрать текст и возвратить 3 результата?

Tags: php, парсер, функции

Всем дорого времени суток.

Есть текст, пример:

> Занимаюсь изготовлением, сборкой и установкой Рекламных вывесок, объемных букв и баннеров. Также печатаю на материале. 89000000000. Все делаю от визиток до вывесок. Весь спектр услуг выполняю. #типография@tipografia

Суть функции вырезать из текста телефон, (мое регулярное выражение `/89\d{9}/`) и вырезать хештег `#типография@tipografia` (единственная динамическая часть в теге "типография" остальная часть не меняется `#******* @tipografia`)

и вывести из функции 3 переменных:

1. `$a` в которой содержится исходный текст без телефона и хештега.
2. `$b` в которой содержится телефон `"89000000000"`.
3. `$c` в которой содержится хештег `"#типография@tipografia"`.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов - сперва получить из строки номер и email, после этого удалить их. Возвращать значения из функции можно как будет удобнее, я для этого использовал функцию [compact()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.compact.php), но можно и просто объявить массив, собрать в него все данные и вернуть массив:

```
<?php

$str = 'Занимаюсь изготовлением, сборкой и установкой Рекламных вывесок, объемных букв и баннеров. Также печатаю на материале. 89000000000. Все делаю от визиток до вывесок. Весь спектр услуг выполняю. #типография@tipografia';

extract(str_parse($str));

// $text  ==  текст
// $tel   ==  телеф.номер
// $email ==  эл.адрес

function str_parse($str) {
    preg_match_all('~\b89\d{9}\b|#[^#\s]+~', $str, $arr);
    $text = preg_replace('~\b89\d{9}\b\.?|#[^#\s]+~', '', $str);
    $tel = $arr[0][0] ?? false;
    $email = $arr[0][1] ?? false;
    return compact('text', 'tel', 'email');
}

?>
<!-- Подставить переменную с номером телефона $tel -->
<textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><?= $tel ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, вызываю функцию передаю ей переменную с текстом str_parse($text), как сделать чтобы отобразился номер?

Мой код:
<textarea rows="17" cols="47" name="text" ><?  str_parse($text);  ?></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант можно так.

```
$text = 'Занимаюсь изготовлением, сборкой и установкой Рекламных вывесок, 
объемных букв и баннеров. Также печатаю на материале. 89000000000. Все делаю 
от визиток до вывесок. Весь спектр услуг выполняю. #типография@tipografia';
$number = preg_replace('~[^0-9]+~','',$text);
$hesh = stristr($text, '#');
$text = str_replace($number, "", $text);
$text = str_replace($hesh, "", $text);
```

Ответ:

```
89000000000
#типография@tipografia
Занимаюсь изготовлением, сборкой и установкой Рекламных вывесок, объемных 
букв и баннеров. Также печатаю на материале. Все делаю от визиток до 
вывесок. Весь спектр услуг выполняю.
```